# SMTP() Faied in PHPmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i have used following code to Send mail using PHP

```
<?php
$sendfrm_name = "Bala";
$sendfrm_id = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
$sendtoname = 'Bala';
$sendto = 'yyyyyy@client.com';
$cc = '';
include("mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
include("mail/class.PHPMailer.php");
include("mail/class.smtp.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail-> isSMTP();
$mail-> Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
//$mail->SMTPDebug   = 2;
$mail-> SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->smtpConnect = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail-> Username = 'aaasasas@gmail.com';
$mail-> Password = 'pwd';
$mail-> SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail-> Port = 587; //587
$mail-> setFrom($sendfrm_id, $sendfrm_name);
$mail-> addAddress($sendto, $sendtoname);
$mail-> addReplyTo($sendto, $sendtoname);
//$mail->addCC($cc);
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Test Mail";
$mail->Body = "Name: ".$sendfrm_name ."<br /> Email: ".$sendfrm_id;
if(!$mail->send())
{
    echo "Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo "1";
}
?>
```

the above code is working in localhost(php version 5.3) but this same code doesnot work in Server..

> Its through failed Error: Mailer Error SMTP() Connection Failed

How to fix this error? and also how to Enable Openssl in linux server?

Comment: Have error log?

Comment: `Mailer Error: SMTP() Connection Failed`@CalosKao

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question you posted before. My answer there provides pointers to how to enable SSL, and you should not be doing any new development using PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

I copy and tested your code, that can work (Both TLS and SSL)

You can enable debug mode to get more detail information.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
```